# Google Analytics SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, for-loop, google-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Google Analytics SDK with my iPhone app.
As it's described in the docs, before I began using the SDK, I've first created a free account at www.google.com/analytics and created a new website profile in that account using a fake but descriptive website URL.

For the created profile tracking status is always "Tracking Not Installed".
So, my question is, will it cause a problem to send tracking requests from my iPhone application? If yes, please advice me what to do then.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the answer...When I run the my app in Simulator, it is not sending trucking requests, but everything is fine, when I run it on the device.